# Restore Ionic Framework CSS

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

Good afternoon! 
I'm having some troubles with the Ionic's CSS.
The issue is that when i use the Google Maps V3, the CSS frmo the Google Maps overrides the original CSS from my Ionic, which affects the other pages of the mobile drastically.
So, I had an idea of a temporary fix for this issue, which would be restoring all the CSS of the framework when pressing the button to change the page.
And as I'm still a newbie, I've got no clue on how to do that (and I also couldn't find it at Google).
Thx for the attention!

Comment: Have you tried moving around the style sheet order (possible put the Maps Css above ionic), Its a dumb suggestion, but may work...

Comment: It was a cordova plugin problem ... I updated the plugins, which I used to make the maps works, and it came back to life! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem: It was a cordova geolocation plugin problem ... I updated the plugins, which I used to make the maps works, and it came back to life! :)
It was not getting the current location of the user (and I've not requested it, but it was failing to open it for that issue).